# background updates in app

Tags: ios, background-task

I create news app that parses social network and get information from it. I saw in Apple documentation in Background Execution and Multitasking that Long-Running Background Tasks can be applied by

> Apps that need to download and process new content regularly Apps that
>   receive regular updates from external accessories

So, can I use it to update my apps news as Long-Running Background Tasks?

Comment: What's the point of updating the news if the app is in the background? Why not wait until it enters foreground?

Comment: I want notify users for news updates and show number of new news

Comment: How will you notify? I'm asking these specifics because there are standard guidelines to follow for most cases.

Comment: with number of new news on app icon badge and local notifications

Comment: Best to handle this server side and do push notifications instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need those background updates? Neither Twitter nor Facebook use those to update the user's feed. You might need them for things like updating user location and showing notifications (just like Foursquare does) but it is quite a battery-darining experience some time.

While you certainly can use them for whatever you want it might not save from an AppStore rejection.

Comment: I want notify users for news updates and show number of new news

Comment: @user3608465 There are 2 ways to do this - either use Push Notifications or update the feed when the user comes back to the app. All other use cases might lead to an AppStore rejection or will render your app unusable.

Comment: yep, I want to use Push Notifications(badge and local). Question is - my app can uses this updates or not? Privet s Kaliningrada, Segera :)

Comment: @user3608465 Privet ;) Yes, you can certainly use this kind of updating (either just updating the badge and sending some short message - suitable for iOS 5,6 or 7; or you can even trigger an app to update in the background with a special Push Notification - but just for iOS 7)

Answer (score 0):

Use iOS 7 **background fetch** - http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/.

It will poll your server, fetch the new items, then if there is any difference toward local content, schedule a simple local notification - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

It won't drain battery, **you neither have to implement push notification services**, however, user will experience as a push notification.

As everyone suggested, the actual news should be fetched in foreground, at every app launch actually. Only some counters, states should be fetched in the background, not the actual content.